# C - Buffer overflow with strcpy() and strncpy()

Tags: c, cs50

I'm taking the CS50 course on edx and I'm supposed to write a code in C that encrypts a message using the Vigenere Cipher. And I did. But the problem is I keep getting buffer overflow.

If I use a short string, like "Meet", it works okay. But if I use a longer string, like "Meet me at the park at eleven am", I get buffer overflow.

If I use `strcpy()` to copy both the key passed in `argv[1]` to another variable (let's say `k`) and the original message (`msg`) to the variable of the encrypted message (`encMsg`), then it erases what I had in `k`.
If I use `strcpy()` again to copy the value of `argv[1]` to `k` one more time, I get buffer overflow in `encMsg` concatenating both strings.

If I use `strccpy()`, it won't get the content of k erased, but it will overflow and concatenate both strings on `encMsg`.

This all happens when I use `GetSting()` (from cs50.h);

If I use `fgets()`, then I will get '\n' at the end of msg and then have to add an if to put a '\0' where that '\n' was, which solves my problem, but I wanted to know if anyone could explain me why all of this happens.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) //Checks if number of command-line arguments is valid
    {
        printf ("usage: ./caesar + key \n");
        return 1;    
    }

    char k[strlen(argv[1])];
    //strcpy(k, argv[1]);         //Saves argument into a string
    strncpy(k, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));

    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(k); x++) 
    {
        if (k[x] < 65 || (k[x] > 90 && k[x] < 97) || k[x] > 122) //Checks if there is any non-alphabetical character in key
        {
            printf ("key must contain only alphabetical characters \n");
            return 1;    
        }
    }

    //printf("Inform the message you want to encrypt: \n");
    string msg = GetString();
    //char msg[255];
    //fgets(msg, 255, stdin);

    char encMsg[strlen(msg)];
    //strcpy(encMsg, msg);
    strncpy(encMsg, msg, strlen(msg));

    //strcpy(k, argv[1]); 

    int y = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < strlen(msg); x++) 
    {
        //if(msg[x] == '\n') msg[x] = '\0';
        if (msg[x] < 65 || (msg[x] > 90 && msg[x] < 97) || msg[x] > 122) encMsg[x] = msg[x];
        else if ((msg[x] + (k[y] - 97 ) > 90 && msg[x] + (k[y] - 97 ) < 97) || msg[x] + (k[y] - 97 ) > 122)
        {
            encMsg[x] = msg[x] + (k[y] - 97) - 26;
            y++;
        }
        else 
        {
            encMsg[x] = msg[x] + (k[y] - 97);
            y++;
        }
        if (y >= strlen(k)) y = 0;
    }

    printf("key     =    %s\n", k);
    printf("msg     =    %s\n", msg);
    printf("encMsg  =    %s\n", encMsg);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (k[x] < 65 || (k[x] > 90 && k[x] < 97) || k[x] > 122)` is the reason there are standard C functions such as `isalpha()`, `isupper()`, and `islower()`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @Olaf. That was a really good reply. But next time, just save yourself the trouble.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, pal. I'm fairly new to C, so I didn't know about those.

Answer (score 4):

This style of code:

```
char k[strlen(argv[1])];
```

leaves no space for a terminating `'\0`' character.  It should be

```
char k[strlen(argv[1]) + 1 ];
```

And as pointed out in the comments, code such as

```
strncpy(k, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
```

will not properly terminate the target string.  Per [the standard for `strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html):

> If the array pointed to by `s2` is a string that is shorter than `n`
>   bytes, NUL characters shall be appended to the copy in the array
>   pointed to by `s1`, until `n` bytes in all are written.

Since the target string *isn't* shorter than `n`, only the non-`NUL` bytes in the source string are copied as there are `n` of them.

Proper code could be

```
strncpy(k, argv[1], 1 + strlen(argv[1]));
```

Comment: Otherwise put, there is `strlen(argv[1])` space for the terminating NUL, but `strncpy(k, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));` __by definition__ does not copy a NUL byte because it is not included in the first `strlen(argv[1])` bytes of `argv[1]`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis That too. I'll add that.